# Testing Akka Persistent FSM Actor with the applying method

Tags: java, akka-testkit, akka-fsm

I am trying to develop an FSM model in AKKA using its Java api. I wish to unit test this feature. I have gone through numerous examples on unit testing Akka FSM actors with lambda support but i couldn't find any relevant example which tests the **.applying** and the **.andthen** method of the same, so that i can be sure that the test covers the custom handle logic derived from the parameters of the DomainEventB.

```
startWith(STATE A, new domain());

    when(STATE A, matchEvent(DomainEventA.class, Domain.class, (domainEventA, domain) -> goTo(STATE B)));

    when(STATE B,
        matchEvent(DomainEventB.class, Domain.class,
            (domainEventB, domain) -> stay()
                .applying(new DomainEventB())
                .andThen(exec(domain -> {
                 // handle logic
                })));
```

Any help/resource preferably in Java will be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you already checked out Akka's own test for inspiration? https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-persistence/src/test/java/akka/persistence/fsm/AbstractPersistentFSMTest.java

Comment: This is very helpful. Thanks a ton !